# Bluetooth File Sharing - Unable to open file for sharing

Tags: android, bluetooth

Bluetooth sharing file between devices, getting:- Unable to open file for Sharing.

I want to send Image stored in Picture directory, and my pic name is : **kitkat.jpg**

Am i giving wrong path ?

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                    "com.android.bluetooth",
                    "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity"));
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                        (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "/kitkat.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st check whether the image path is correct.

check manifest permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

also give permission to read External Storage

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and lastly do this

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image"));
```

if image is in picture folder then path will be like this

```
final String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
            (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/kitkat.jpg"
```

Comment: I have stored image in Picture Directory, namely: kitkat.jpg ... tell am i providing wrong path